# if there is str('a') or str('b') or str('c') in a user input then do something

Tags: python, string

I would like to put multiple strings for one **in** statement one one line:

```
input = str(raw_input(''))   
if str('a') or ('b') or ('c') in str(input):
    print "a string"
else:
    print "no"
```

Is it possible to have multiple strings for a single **in** statement?

Comment: I think you can do like: `if(input in ('a', 'b', 'c')):`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, that will check if `input` equals to either of these three strings.

Comment: @poke yes, is it not what he wants?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: OP wants to check if any of those strings are in `input`.

Comment: Note that `str('a')` results in the value `'a'`, which is shorter.  You could also write `str(str('a'))`, or `str(str(str(str('a'))))`, but it's all just `'a'`.

Comment: @poke ok OP need  either on one is substring of input ?

Comment: better title say that do you wants, avoid code in title if possible.

Answer (score 6):

First of all `str('a') == 'a'` (because `'a'` is already a string), so you can leave that out.

```
'a' or 'b' or 'c' in input
```

This expression is parsed as the following:

```
('a') or ('b') or ('c' in input)
```

So you are checking if `'a'` or `'b'` evalute to true, which is the case. If you want to check them all using the `in` operator, you have to explicitely specify that:

```
'a' in input or 'b' in input or 'c' in input
```

You can also simplify that then:

```
any(x in input for x in ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Comment: its `'input'` should be consists of `'a', 'b', 'c'` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Rather if any of `a`, `b` or `c` are substrings of `input`. So `foo` would be false, but `bar` would be true because an `a` is in there.

Answer (score 3):

It is, but what you wrote does something entirely different. It checks to see if `str('a')` is truthy, if `'b'` is truthy, or if `'c'` is in `input`. While Python is very readable, it doesn't make assumptions about what you write. You have to be explicit:

```
if 'a' in input or 'b' in input or 'c' in input:
    ...
```

Or:

```
strings = ('a', 'b', 'c')

if any(s in input for s in strings):
    ...
```

Calling `str()` with a string argument is pointless. Also, `input` is the name of a builtin, so I suggest you rename your variable.

Comment: Should be `any()`, not `all()`.

Comment: Isnt the second solution an `AND` condition and not a `OR` condition? Ok, already corrected :)

Comment: its `'input'` should be consists of `'a', 'b', 'c'` ?